# How to make a menu item that is not a link

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-pages, hub-site

We are looking at our navigation menu, and we'd like some items to have submenus, but not clickable. Here's an example structure:

- About
- Products

  - Product 1
  - Product 2
  - Product 3
- Contact

In this example, I would like "Products" to not be a link. Clicking would only open the submenu (or not, whatever), but not take you to a new page. Does this make sense?

We are using Modern Sharepoint pages and hub site navigation menus.

**Update:**
Here's what I have in Site Settings:

[image]

I click on Quick Launch then Add Header:

[image]

And it still requires me to add a link:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is not possible in modern team sites unfortunately. Agreed doesn't make sense at all, but that is indeed the case.

Comment: This is possible - enter a "#" into the "Type the Web address:" field

Comment: @jkobier, when I did that before, it still made the link clickable, and would scroll you to the top of the page. I wanted nothing at all to happen when you click except to expand the menu. Anyways, this is an older problem since the "Header" option is working now (it wasn't when I asked the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this with my own hub site and took screen grabs.

1. Edit the left rail navigation

   [image: Step One]
2. Click on the '+' to get the Add a link dialog
   Choose "Header" and enter "Display name"
   Click "OK"
   [image: Step 2]
3. Repeat the process for your sub-item
   If you want to have a link to a document or list item, use the URL option
   Otherwise just create another Header
   [image: Step Three]
4. Select your first sub-item and drag it up to the main header
   It will move the sub-item under the main header.
   Repeat this step for all of your sub-items and click "Save" when finished to preserve your work.
   [image: Step Four]
5. The main header will appear as a drop down item
   [image: Step Five]
6. Clicking on the main header should just expand the drop down menu and show you the sub-item
   [image: Step Six]

   ---

   Please Note:
   These instructions are specifically written for a SharePoint Online Hub Site.
   They are current as of the date of this post.

Comment: What the heck? How is this working? This is exactly what I tried before and it wouldn't work! But now, after looking at your answer and going back to my setup to prove you wrong, the Header option is there, just as it's supposed to be. Maybe there was a temporary issue? Maybe the Header feature wasn't rolled out to my tenant? Whatever it was, it's working now and your answer is the winner! The thoroughness and pictures are worth the +50 bounty all by themselves! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can activate web feature - SharePoint Server Publishing.

After that, Navigation settings will displayed in Site Settings as on picture below. Now it will be possible to add heading without link.

Also you can access navigation settings by the link - http://YOUR_SITE/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx

[image]

Comment: And this will work on Modern Pages and Hub Navigation menus?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can try. It will 100% work for classic experience. It was not clear from your question that you are using modern pages and hub sites.

Comment: I gave you an upvote since my question didn't say it, but yeah, I'm using Modern pages in sharepoint online, and this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In the Modern Experience, go to the Site Settings page.  From here, you can click on the Edit Links button below the Quick Launch bar on the left.  For whatever reason, from this menu, it will allow you to enter a Heading without a URL.  No idea why it works here and nowhere else, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

One quick option is to have your URL field be a pound/hash symbol ("#").  This will make the link still 'active' for all intents and purposes, ie: Branding, but the click function will take the user nowhere.

Comment: I tried that. And instead of leaving it as a hash link, it replaced it with the URL of my hub site home page.

Answer (score 0):

My SP Online instance does not permit me to add a heading without a URL, even when I go to Site Settings -> Quick Launch (under Look and Feel) and click on "New Heading." However, here is what DOES WORK for me:

1. In the Quick Launch menu that you access from Site Settings under Look and Feel, click on "Edit Links" in the Quick Launch bar off to the left (this ONLY works in the Quick Launch settings page off of Site Settings, NOT from the Quick Launch bar on any other page of your site...don't ask me why)
2. Click on "+Link"
3. In the "Add a Link" window that pops up, enter the name of your heading under "Text to display." Leave the "Address" field blank. Click OK. And that's it. You should have a non-linked quick launch heading now.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was easier for me than the instructions posted, since these did not work for me.

What actually worked, silly enough was that I changed the vertical menu view to horizontal in the "Change the Look/Navigation" Site Settings Menu.

Once the menu is in horizontal view, you edit the menu item and you will see the "label" option.  this blanks out the link field.

Once you save it, change it back to horizontal mode and voila!  when you select the field, it shows you the context (sub-links) below... I does not go anywhere.

This solved my problem, hope it helps with yours.