# Unable to create subheading or child heading in Quicklaunch section in SharePoint online modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-experience, quick-launch

I am trying to create a below Navigation structure in the Quick launch available in my sharepoint online modern site.

```
Heading1
Link1
Subheading1
      SubLink1
      SubLink2
Link2
Link3
Heading2
```

Basically I want to create child-heading[Level2] node inside it's parent heading[Level1] node. How can I achieve the same ?

Please help me to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the answer given in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/260737/how-to-make-a-menu-item-that-is-not-a-link) post. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

We couldn't get this work in Structure Navigation.

As a workaround,please use [modern SharePoint navigation-cascading menu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/plan-navigation-modern-experience) to achieve your requirement.(Please note we need to **Deactivate** the publishing feature in this site)

Cascading menu supports up to three levels of navigation in your menu.

Simple test for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My site uses "Team Site without Office 365 Group" template. Only in communication site it is allowing to create labels/heading with cascading manner. Have you tried the test reference within a "Team Site without Office 365 Group" site?

Comment: I tested it, you could drag labels to create a cascading list within a "Team Site without Office 365 Group" site.